# Are TCP packets fast enough?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

I just made a small WebSocket server in C++ in order to make a simple video game. I read on the internet that we should use UDP over TCP in video games. But there isn't any UDP sockets in HTML5, do you think TCP would be fast enough to send a lot of positions every seconds of all the players?

Comment: Tricky to answer, as you haven't defined "fast enough" or "lots"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends upon the latency involved and most heavily on how much packet loss there is.
If there is no packet loss then TCP is almost as fast as UDP, with exception to TCP having to do a connection 'handshake' to establish the initial connection as well as a small overhead in ACKs being returned.

Comment: Good to hear, and what's the best way to reduce packet loss?

Comment: You can't really because it has to do with all the intermediate routers and even the wiring between your server and the players.
The reason that a packet is lost is because its data has become corrupted, perhaps due to a noisy line. The router detects that the packet is faulty by looking at its 'finger print' (a CRC checksum) and drops the packet if it is corrupted.
In this scenario TCP will try to resend the packet where as UDP just drops it. This is why it is good for things like position updates because you can afford to miss one, you just get the next, no need to hold up the show :)

Comment: Hopefully with this insight you can appreciate why it is a tricky question to answer.